# android studio Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

Tags: android, android-studio

I've googled enough for this problem and followed the examples, but it didn't work, so I'm here to ask a question

Android studio version is 4.0.1 and it's in the picture.Do you have any resources or advice that might help me? please

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Where are you from? I think your access is restricted.
Change your IP to another country to solve the problem

Comment: I'm Korean. How do I change IP?

Comment: In my case, it was because the address I added to Maven changed. It was not an ip problem at all. Thank you for your interest.